# How can I remove paystack payment method in Laravel Project?

Tags: laravel, memory-management, project

I have downloaded a project from GitHub which has an integrated pay stack payment method. But I want to remove it. Instead of that payment method, I want to add just an extra webpage there how to do that? Where to change to remove this payment method? I am new to the laravel project.

Comment: What package did you download?